# program return data to client error

Tags: anchor, anchor-client, borsh

I'm returning a `Result<u64>` from my program and want to get that value in the typescript client. I'm using anchor, and attempting to use the functions below:

```
const getReturnLog = (confirmedTransaction) => {
    const data = confirmedTransaction.meta.returnData.data
    const buffer = Buffer.from(data[0], data[1]);
    return [data, buffer];
};

const getBN = (t): BN => {
    const [data, buffer] = getReturnLog(t)
    const reader = new borsh.BinaryReader(buffer);

    console.log(data)
    console.log(buffer)

    return reader.readU64()
};
```

I'm using this general approach successfully to return arrays, but for u64 I get this error:

`Error: Expected buffer length 8 isn't within bounds`

with console.log (as printed in the function above):

```
[ 'c9an9AM=', 'base64' ]
<Buffer 73 d6 a7 f4 03>
```

Also see:
https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/tests/cpi-returns/tests/cpi-return.ts

Any help would be much apprecaited! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`meta.returnData.data` is trimmed all of the least significant bit (LE) to the right from your program returned value. In this case, it's missing 3 zero bytes at the end of the buffer.

I think a better approach would be not using parsed transaction `meta.returnData.data` but write up your own code to slice the transaction log without trimming data similar to Anchor return cpi tests:

```
  const getReturnLog = (confirmedTransaction) => {
    const prefix = "Program return: ";
    let log = confirmedTransaction.meta.logMessages.find((log) =>
      log.startsWith(prefix)
    );
    log = log.slice(prefix.length);
    const [key, data] = log.split(" ", 2);
    const buffer = Buffer.from(data, "base64");
    return [key, data, buffer];
  };
```

Comment: thanks, i suspected it was something like that. i wonder why it's trimmed.

one thing to note, for future readers, is that if you are doing any CPI calls within your program you'll need to include your program ID in the prefix.